# alternatives to User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Afternoon all,

Im am displaying the username on a web page to state who has locked the web page for editing.  I am using the following code...

```
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lock.LockedBy) Then

         lock.LockedBy = User.Identity.Name
         hdnIsLockedBy.Value = User.Identity.Name
         lock.AgendaID = Integer.Parse(lblAgendaNumber.Text)

  End If
```

I understand that User.Identity.Name brings back the Domain\Name.  I was wondering if i can just pull back the name of the user only as i cant see any suitable alternatives?

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that the domain name will be the same for all users, simply strip it from `User.Identity.Name` using `String.Replace`

```
User.Identity.Name.Replace("MyDomainName\", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do something like this:

```
lock.LockedBy = User.Identity.Name.Contains("\\")? User.Identity.Name.Substring(name.IndexOf("\\")+1):User.Identity.Name;
```

If it's something you are doing often, move it to a function.